# R: data inconsistency between Worldbank data in R and exported to csv

Tags: r, export-to-csv, largenumber

I am performing calculations with Worldbank data.
For GDP, these are large numbers.
When I manipulate the data in R, they are different from when I export them to csv and manipulate them there.

For example, in R I see the 1960 GDP for Argentina as "115573868508".
Exported to csv and then displayed in Excel it shows as "11557386850815".
There are simply two digits more at the end.

Looking at some other comments I see R has certain limits for large numbers.
Yet, when downloading the data from the Worldbank, I didn't get a warning.

```
library(wbstats) # to access World Bank data

new_wb_cache <- wbcache() 
# get all data; next line extracts GDP, which shows the problem

gdp <- wb(country = tc$iso3c, indicator = "NY.GDP.MKTP.KD", startdate = 1960, enddate = 2018)

typeof(gdp$GDP) 
# results in "double"

gdp1960 <- gdp[which(gdp$date == 1960),1:3] 
# We only need this to understand the issue

write.csv(gdp1960, "gdp1960.csv")
# importing this csv into Excel shows the inconsistency.
```

I'd like to understand how I can handle the Worldbank data - or large numbers - and what set of data to trust (R or csv???) so I can perform meaningful calculation with Worldbank data.

Comment: This is strange. Looking at the examples, I would expect  "NY.GDP.MKTP.KD" to be in scientific notation. [see the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wbstats/vignettes/Using_the_wbstats_package.html)

Answer (score 2):

the value for Argentina is 115573868508.15
You will see it in R if you change print options:

```
options(scipen = 999, digits = 15)
```

It seems that Excel has problems with decimal separator. You can also check the value in csv file using text editor.

Comment: Thank you all. That was indeed the problem - a beginner's problem.
Most important was the hint: "go and look at the csv-file". Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The value when exported is not `11557386850815` as you indicated but rather `115573868508.15`, ie two extra digits of precision. In R you're seeing 115573868508 rather than 115573868508.15 because the default number of significant digits to print is 7. You will see the full value in R by increasing the number of displayed digits:

```
options(digits=15)
```